# Which Dynamics 365 trial "app" to choose to have a full featured CRM organization?

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-365, dynamics-crm-365

**Context**

I would like to have a sandbox Dynamics 365 online (CRM) organization. I decided to set up an [online trial](https://t). When I start to create MS asks me to choose an "app" (see attached picture).

The organization is for testing and POC purposes in C# client project.

**Question**

Which one to choose to have a full featured online Dynamics 365 (CRM) organization?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/admin/try-dynamics-365-online) says you can choose one of it, later you can add more apps by going to [Office 365 admin center](https://portal.office.com/) using Global administrator login to administer it. App switcher will help you to navigate between apps.

Here’s my puzzle solver: (old acronym vs Dynamics 365 for)

CRM = Sales + Customer Service + Field Service
AX = Finance and Operations + Retail

Latest additions & acquisitions:

HR solutions = Talent
PM solutions = Project Service Automation